# Perl read seek tell, and text files. Too many bytes being read. Layers and newline handling

Tags: perl, seek, tell, binmode

I've a Perl script which analyses a text file (can be UNIX or windows line endings) storing file offsets when it find something of interest.

```
open(my $fh, $filename);
my $groups;
my %hash;
while(<$fh>) {
   if($_ =~ /interesting/ ) {
      $hash{$groups++}{offset} = tell($fh);
   }
}
close $fh;
```

Then later on in the script I want to produce 'n' copies of the text file but with additional content at each 'interesting' area.  To achieve this I loop through the hash of offsets:

```
foreach my $group (keys %hash) {
   my $href = $hash{$group};
   my $offset = $href->{offset};

   my $top;
   open( $fh, $file);
   read( $fh, $top, $offset);
   my $bottom = do{local $/; <$fh>};
   close $fh;

   $href->{modified} = $top . "Hello World\n" . $bottom;
}
```

The problem is the read command is reading too many bytes.  I suspect this is a line ending issue as the number of bytes (chars?) out is the same as the line number.  Using Notepad++ the `tell()` command is returning the real offset to point of interest, but using that offset value in `read()` returns characters past the point of interest.

I've tried adding `binmode($fh)` straight after the `open()` command prior to the `read()`.  This does find the correct position in the text file, but then I get (CR + CRLF) output and the text file is full of double carriage returns.

I've played with layers :crlf, :bytes, but no improvement.

Bit stuck!

Comment: Why don't you `seek` to the positions, opening the file just once?

Comment: `CRLF` isn't a character. A Windows text file has lines ending with the *two* characters `CR` and `LF` or carriage return and linefeed. It's hard to believe your file is *"full of double carriage returns"*.

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I add binmode().  As a string of bytes: /***********************************************/CRCRLF/*   Linker Script      */CRCRLF

Comment: @Borodin, it's actually easy to believe that.  CRCRLF is exactly what you get when you print `"\r\n"` to a filehandle with the `:crlf` layer.  Perl prints the CR as-is, then turns the LF into CRLF.

Comment: @cjm: Maybe, but there is no sign of any CRs being printed in the code. Chris, do you print anything other than `"\n"` at the end of a line?

Comment: @Borodin, he's reading a CRLF file with `binmode` and writing with `:crlf` (probably implicit because running on Windows).

Comment: @cjm: Yes, that would fit the theory but we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

- A hash with a continuous range of integers as keys should be an array.
- You are storing a copy of the *entire file* for every occurrence of `/interesting/`
- It sounds like what you need to do is this

  ```
  open(my $fh, $filename);
  while (<$fh>) {
    print;
    print "Hello World\n" if /interesting/;
  }
  ```

Comment: I've tried to dumb down my example to avoid confusion.  Yes, I need to produce a copy of the entire file 'n' times with /interesting/ sections appended to.  The text file is actually a linker script and the /interesting/ parts are .input sections.   At the end the Perl script will go multi-threaded calling LD with each of these modified linker scripts..  My issue is the read() command returning too many bytes.

Comment: I would have thought this was a job for [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie::File), but there should be no problem with just using `binmode $fh`. Yes you will get `LF` or `CR` + `LF` at the end of the lines, depending where the file came from, but the value from `seek` will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

From `perldoc -f read`:

```
read FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH,OFFSET
read FILEHANDLE,SCALAR,LENGTH
```

So, when you do:

```
read( $fh, $top, $offset);
```

your `$offset` is actually a length.  Decide how many characters you need to read.  `read` does not respect line-endings, it reads the number of bytes specified.

If you want to read a line, then don't use `read`, use:

```
seek($fh, $offset, 0);
$top = <$fh>;
```

Is your file full of two new-lines, or are you adding one with a `print` statement?

Answer (score 0):

My standard way to handle this, when the input file isn't ginormous, is to slurp the file in and normalize line endings, storing each line as an array element.  I sometimes have to deal with Windows (`CR`+`LF`) and UNIX (`LF` only) and Mac (`CR` only) line endings in the same batch of files.  The same script needs to run correctly across all three platforms too.

I generally take a belt-and-braces approach when having to deal with such things.  One way that ought to work:

```
sub read_file_into_array
{
    my $file = shift;
    my ($len, $cnt, $data, @file);

    open my $fh, "<", $file         or die "Can't read $file: $!";
    seek $fh, 0, 2                  or die "Can't seek $file: $!";
    $len = tell $fh;
    seek $fh, 0, 0                  or die "Can't seek $file: $!";

    $cnt = read $fh, $data, $len;
    close $fh;

    $cnt == $len or die "Attempted to read $len bytes; got $cnt";

    $data =~ s/\r\n/\n/g;       # Convert DOS line endings to UNIX
    $data =~ s/\r/\n/g;         # Convert Mac line endings to UNIX

    @file = split /\n/, $data;  # Split on UNIX line endings

    return \@file;
}
```

Then do all your processing on the lines in `@file`.  For your 'interesting' tags, you would store an array index rather than a file offset.  The array index is essentially the line number in the original file, counting starting at 0 instead of 1.

To actually augment the files, instead of looping through hash keys, why not construct a hash consisting of line-number => thing-to-append pairs, generating the augmented file like this:

```
sub generate_augmented_file
{
    my $file   = shift @_;   # array ref
    my $extras = shift @_;   # hash ref of line => extra pairs
    my $text;        

    foreach my $line ( 0 .. scalar( $file ) - 1 )
    {
        $text .= $file->[$line];
        $text .= $extras->{$line} if defined $extras->{$line};
        $text .= "\n";
    }

    return $text;
}
```